# I know it is formally incorrect, but does "He neither likes apples nor oranges" sound bad?

Tags: neither-nor

I know the correct statement is "He likes neither apples nor oranges", but I also know that we can say "He does not like apples or oranges" and this puts the negation before the verb and it sounds better to me like that, with a negation before the verb. Therefore, for me, "He neither likes apples nor oranges" sounds better than "He likes neither  apples nor oranges". Logically, I see it as a shortcut for "He neither likes apples nor likes oranges", the second "likes" being implicit.

My question is: in day to day usage among native English speakers does putting *neither* before the verb in this sentence sound OK or does it sound weird?   I don't care about rules. I care about how it sounds and that ordinary people can understand.

Comment: He neither likes apples nor eats them. The neither goes before the verb when there are two different verbs. Otherwise it does not.

Comment: The ordering of your sentence is a bit off.  You are saying, *He likes neither apples nor [does he like] oranges.*  The ordering in your sentence, however, is better suited for a sentence such as, *He neither likes apples nor dislikes apples.*

Comment: Lambie I made it clear that I know the rule that you stated. Elliek, are you saying that "He likes neither apples nor  oranges" is also incorrect? I don't get it. We can use the neither-nor combination with nouns.

Comment: I don't see it as "incorrect" at all. Merely a variant. It certainly doesn't affect understanding,

Comment: From [Good English: The mechanics of composition](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22incorrect+I+neither+like+him+nor+his%22) (1918)  - *The following sentences are incorrect : **I neither like him nor his father. He not only asked him to go but also to take his luggage with him**. Here they are corrected, **I like neither him nor his father. He asked him not only to go but also to take his luggage with him**.* It is a rather pedantic position, though.

Comment: The sample sentence  you give is awkward and wrong as it does not create parallelism in your sentence. Also, it does sound weird and probably would never be uttered by a native speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, both of your constructs will be correctly understood by your audience. With that in mind, I would not use *incorrect* to describe either of them.  This answer is directed at determining which construct is pedantically *better*.

Neither/Nor is negation (neither) coupled with the associated negative conjunction (nor).  The location of *Neither* in relationship to the sentence's subject or verb determines what is being negated and both sides of the *Nor* must balance (i.e. describe the same thing).

In sentence #1, *He likes neither apples nor oranges*, neither comes before *apples* and negates apples.  The nor must then also apply to negating something similar, in this case any noun will do (oranges, onions, buzzards).

In sentence #2, *He neither likes apples nor dislikes apples*, neither comes before *likes* and negates *likes*.  It does not negate *apples*.  Since we have negated *like* we need to balance our *Nor* statement with something that can be compared to *likes* (i.e. dislikes, loves, hates). You could technically use any verb, *He neither likes apples nor swims rivers*, but such usage would apply to specific, contextually understood situations.

Negate two nouns or two verbs or two adjectives or two adverbs but do not mix your negations.  That's the whole point.

*He condescends neither leisurely nor casually.  It's all business.*

Comment: My pedantic version would never be *He likes neither apples nor oranges*, because I don't want  to negate *apples* and *oranges*. I want to negate *likes* , because it conveys more directly the feeling. So, my pedantic version would be *He neither likes apples nor likes oranges*. Seen that way, I feel the non pedantic version has a logical purpose, which is to avoid a repetition that the audience does not need.

Comment: @Lambie - I know they will understand because there is only one way to understand.  Answer updated with nod to the two verb bit.

Comment: @user135315 *You* and EllieK are misusing the word pedantic. You can't imagine how funny it sounds to a native ear as used here.

Answer (score 0):

neither and nor have to precede the parts of speech or phrases to which they apply so that there is **parallelism in the sentence**:

**NOUNS**

- He likes **neither apples nor oranges**.
- They played **neither waltzes nor mazurkas.**

**VERBS**

- They **neither sweep the floor nor clean it.**
- We neither **fund** those parties nor **support** them.
- You have been **neither seeing those people nor communicating** with them.
- Alternate wording: You have neither been seeing those people nor been communicating with them. (Here, the second *been* is often left out in speech.)

**ADJECTIVES**

- She is **neither rude nor polite**.
- Though that was an intentional mistake, it was **neither funny nor amusing**.

**ADVERBS**

- The man spoke **neither well nor badly**.
- The machine whirred **continually and loudly**.

Neither/nor is generally associated with somewhat formal speech and writing in standard speech or grammar. Generally, a speaker who is not trying to be **formally** emphatic, will use a negative verb and forgo neither/nor in favor of either/or.